# generate Word Document from PHP with header and footer on each page

Tags: php, html, css

I am able to generate Word Document from this code

```
<?php
   header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; Filename=SaveAsWordDoc.docx");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=Windows-1252\">
 <title>Saves as a Word Doc</title>
</head>
  <body>
    <h1>Header</h1>
      This text can be seen in word
    <ul>
      <li>List 1</li>
      <li>List 2</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to add headers and footer in each page of the word document. How can I do this?

Comment: We tried for very long time in school project without success until finding https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord. Overkill for our project but in long run saved many hours. Also see http://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Side note: your HTML contains bogus `\\` characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to produce real word documents instead of html saved as word, I would suggest a library like https://phpword.codeplex.com/

Adding a Header and Footer should be pretty simple with this.

**Edit:** use the repo on [Github](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord) instead (Thanks to Mark for the correction)

Comment: The Codeplex site is long dead and wish it could be buried.... the official repo for PHPWord is on [github](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord)

Comment: yeah, I found it also.. but Is there a way to do it without using any third party libraries?

Comment: @KimCarlo - You wont get headers and footers without using a native Word format file, HTML is not a substitute: and the alternative to using a third-party library is writing your own library.... good luck, that's several man-years of work for writing a genuine word document writer

Comment: @Mark Baker - oh didn't know, it was just the first result from a quick google.

Comment: @ckay - We wish we could remove it from codeplex; but the site won't allow it (and trying to contact the codeplex administrators is pretty useless)

Answer (score 0):

Of course, this has nothing to do with Microsoft Word format. It's just good old HTML with a wrong extension to trick the computer into opening it with a word processor.

In your computer, Microsoft word happens to figure out the file format and opens it. In mine, LibreOffice Writer does so as well but Microsoft Word does not:

[image: Could not open file]

Even if you had a controlled environment with a known word processor that accepts the deal, you still have the problem that HTML and CSS are mainly designed for screen devices and features for printable media are less appropriate. In particular, I believe that per-page headers and footers are not available at the moment. They may exist in some third-party programs ased on HTML —I recall reading about some publishing software that uses a custom version of CSS to obtain printable books— but certainly not on the HTML engine used by standard word processors.

So you're mostly playing on thin eyes to say the best.

To sum up:

- If you need DOCX format, you'd better serve actual DOCX.
- If you just want something *printable*, I suggest you switch to PDF.